# This simple function does not work. Why? I get "unexpected identifier" error

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

My train of thought to this function: I created an arrow function with 3 parameters and put it inside the `const omg` variable. This function should simply add up numbers 2, 3, 4, and I stored that into a random `let sum` variable. The result should be returned automatically.

```
const omg = (a, b, c) => let sum = a + b + c;

const lala = omg(2,3,4);
console.log(lala);
```

Comment: why a variable without use?

Comment: I simply needed to store the operation of adding up somewhere no? So I created a new `let sum` variable. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not returning anything at the end of your function, u don't need the sum variable declaration:

```
const omg = (a, b, c) => a + b + c;
```

Here is a more verbose version of the fix:

```
const omg = (a, b, c) => {
  const sum = a + b + c;
  return sum;
};
```

Comment: I thought I needed to store a + b + c operation into a variable, otherwise it would be not returned.

Comment: I am returning the total sum of a + b + c ? At least that is how I get the `return`. I passed in arguments 2,3,4 and I should get `returned` number 9.

Comment: The problem is that u are using an arrow function without an explicit return, u are storing the result of the sum inside the function but u you are not returning it at the end.

Comment: Ah, ok, I uderstand. But could I return it in this case explicitly like this?   ``const omg = (a, b, c) => let sum = a + b + c;
return let;
const lala = omg(2,3,4);
console.log(lala);``   It does not work

Comment: u need to use `{}` for arrow functions with more than one line, like the second version of my solution.